# Dundas vs ComponentArt which one is better

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, charts, dundas, componentart

Planning to buy a charting solution (for ASP.NET), narrowed down to Dundas and componentArt.

Is there a feature comparison sheet, comparing these two components?

Has anyone used both of these and found any one of them to be better than the other?

I had used ComponentArt in a project before and was impressed with its 3d like color settings, dundas look bland comparitively...

[EDIT]
Want to use it on .net Framework 2.0
Anyone as any comparison sheet for the two, **it is surprising that we don't have such buyers guide or comparative reviews available for commercial components.**

Comment: Not sure if you heard about MS licensing parts of Dundas for SSRS?  
http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/36202
If you are using SQL Reporting Services you can get a lot of the Dundas charting for free.

Answer (score 2):

Binoj,

Have you seen [the Microsoft chart controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)? They are free.

Comment: I like em, but cant use them, I want it for .net 2.0 :(

Comment: Microsoft purchased rights to Dundas charts some time ago. The Microsoft Chart controls are the Dundas chart controls, albeit limited in some respects. If you can't use Dundas' chart controls, I don't think you will be able to use Microsofts. ;)

Comment: @jrista it's also worth nothing that when MS bought the dundas (5.5) source and rights, they also poached the lead dundas .net developer. (http://blogs.msdn.com/alexgor/archive/2008/09/04/welcome-to-my-blog.aspx). Alex has been improving the MS version of the library for some time and I would argue that it's featureset, while different from Dundas progression, has progressed as well and should not be seen as inferior to Dundas.

Comment: I don't think MS supports this library except with bug fixes. Don't expect any new functionality in this library ever.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up rejecting both of them after some frustrating development and getting this: www.simplechart.net/
The support is better, the enterprise licences are a lot cheaper and more importantly it just works without any fuss.

Answer (score 1):

As I worked with Dundas Chart for a Windows application in .NET 2.0, I can say that they have the state of art where it comes to Chart display... you can do particularly everything with a Chart.  I used to use the winforms and ignore the "Dundas Trial version" image of every chart.

They are in the market for several years and are one of the first choices, but the license value is to much when, sometimes, we need simple things.

For example, for a **finance application** I would defiantly go to **Dundas Charts**, but for a simple chart that gives **simples results** (even with several series), I would consider to see the free products out there like **Microsoft Chart Control** or any other...

Both products (Dundas and ComponentArt) have trial versions, try yourself, see the **Forums** of both and see how and **how quick they answer** a community question, check the **Wiki** / **Tutorials**, this is what you will use most after choosing a Component, no matter what it is.

Hope it helps you decide.

Answer (score 1):

Nevron Chart has at least as many features as Dundas Chart and the image quality of ComponentArt - but is much faster. The pricing is just right and is suitable for both simple and advanced charting (financial, scientific etc.) - see the demos - http://chartexamples.nevron.com/.

Comment: Gosh I remember you guys - I used these controls back in the classic ASP days, they were quite good as I recall.

Answer (score -1):

I have had great experiences working with Dundas. They are fairly easy to use, well documented and have great support. I have called and emailed them with questions and they are incredibly helpful. Also, the charts look way better than any other I have seen. I searched and found about 10 controls, and Dundas was the best.

The only thing that it lacks is 3D charts...but I guess they will add it soon!